# What style guide puts authors' names in all caps?

Tags: citations

I tried using the "Search by example" feature CSL tool (http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/) but couldn't find any exact matches. Here are some examples:

In-text:

(DORMONT and HUBER, 2006)

References:

DORMONT, B. & HUBER, H. 2006. Causes of Health Expenditure Growth: the Predominance of Changes in Medical Practices Over Population Ageing. ANNALES D’ÉCONOMIE ET DE STATISTIQUE, 188-217.

Comment: whatever it is, it makes my eyes itch.

Comment: Well, where did you find that formatting and what style guide does that publication adhere to?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this is a remnant of an old convention.

In historic styles, the author name must be emphasized. Emphasis can be achieved through all or small caps, letter-spacing, italics, or bold face (in aproximate historic order). There are examples for all types of emphasis of author names in historic texts. Which style of emphasis was used was a convention of the (typographic) culture of the time as well as dictated by the contemporary limitations of the printing process.

Boldface is a more recent development and has replaced all caps and letter-spacing almost completely in printed texts. Those (house) styles that still emphasize the author name, usually use boldface today. Some university institutes still require all caps in master's or doctoral theses. Until about twenty years ago academic theses (and in fact many academic publications with a small print run) had to be typed on a typewriter, where capitalization is the only means of emphasis. The current requirement might come from the typewritten layout.

Today, some book designers use all/small cap emphasis for aesthetic reasons and better readability. It is, as far as I know, no longer recommended in any style guide.